# Repeating pandas Series with specific order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, repeat

Repeating pandas Series with *repeat()* function:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
s.repeat(2)
```

```
0    a
0    a
1    b
1    b
2    c
2    c
dtype: object
```

Need to get output like this:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) if performance is important:

```
a = s.loc[np.tile(s.index, 2)]
print (a)
0    a
1    b
2    c
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [25]: %timeit (s.loc[np.tile(s.index, 2000)])
612 µs ± 26.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit (pd.concat([s] * 2000))
22.2 ms ± 251 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

EDIT:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
print (s)

a = s.loc[np.tile(s.index, 2)]
print (a)
2015-01-01    a
2015-01-02    b
2015-01-03    c
2015-01-01    a
2015-01-02    b
2015-01-03    c
dtype: object
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works with DateTimeIndex: **AttributeError:** *'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'loc'*

Comment: @Warrior404 - There is not some typo? For me working well. Also what is your pandas version?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to convert 'DatetimeIndex' to Series. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from pandas concat function as follow

```
 pd.concat([s] * 2)
```